# Is there a way to a remove a particular signal from a slot

Tags: c++, qt

I have a scenario in which different classes dynamically attach to a thread by connecting its signal to their slots. My question is whether it is possible to unsubscribe again? Is there a way to remove signal-slot connection?

Comment: Can http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#disconnect be of any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [QT documentation](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Understanding_Signals_and_Slot_in_Qt), down near the bottom. It says that

> Disconnect can be used to remove the connection.
>
> disconnect(sender0, SIGNAL(overflow()),receiver1, SLOT(handleMathError()))

Another good resource that also mentions `disconnect` is [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_Qt).